# Order joomla query by title

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I have to order the articles inside a query by their title.

My query:

```
<?php
    $catId = 43;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "'";
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery($query); 
    $articles = $db->loadObjectList(); 
    foreach($articles as $article){

    }
?>
```

Comment: In the following statement `$query->order('id DESC'); ` you're ordering the results by `id`. Have you tried replacing the `id` column with the `title` one?

Comment: Sorry the id code was also not working. This was a test, i edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Change $query->order('id DESC'); to

$query->order('title DESC');

or ASC if you want :)

Comment: When i try this i get the following error:  "Call to a member function order() on a non-object in".

Comment: My bad.
I was actually meaning the format that Yoleth uses in the "second one".
In fact your code doesn't create a query object, which is why you get the error. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

2 options, the first one you add order by title in tour request :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "' order by title asc";
```

The second one, which is better, you use the joomla query builder :

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')->from('#__content')->where('catid = '.$catId)->order('title asc');
$db->setQuery($query);
```